# Dataframe String Separation

Tags: dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbVAm.png)

How do I extract each column as one column instead of (year, month, day) format???
Please refer to the photo

```
def temp(i):
 i = str(i)
 year = i[0:4]
 moth = i[4:6]
 day = i[6:8]
 return year,moth,day

profile_drop["year","moth","day"] = profile_drop["became_member_on"].apply(temp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it isn't directly your question, the easiest way to extract the date is convert it to datetime and then use pandas bulit-in operation:

```py
profile_drop["became_member_on_date"] = pd.to_datetime(profile_drop["became_member_on"], format='%Y%m%d')
profile_drop['year'] = profile_drop["became_member_on_date"].dt.year
profile_drop['month'] = profile_drop["became_member_on_date"].dt.month
profile_drop['day'] = profile_drop["became_member_on_date"].dt.day
```

In this snippet I first converted the string to a full datetime using `pd.to_datetime` (and explicitly mentioned the format how to parse) and then extract each relevant year/month/day just by calling to `.year` over the date column.
It is also a way to avoid `.apply` which is not recommended to use unless you have to

A classic [XY Question](https://xyproblem.info/).